# react redux containers send state to another container

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello I have an `action` to get data from my backend and then I created a new container and I use this state and I created an action to filter this state, and then when it clicks back to my component product the products that were filtered

**My action fetch:**

```
  export const fetchProduct = () => {
      console.log('action')
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchStarted());

      api
        .get('/products')
        .then(res => {
          dispatch(fetchSucess(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(fetchFailed(err.message));
        });
    };
  };
```

**My reducer fetch:**

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
  };

export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {    
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          ...state, products: action.data
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**My container product:**

```
class HomeProducts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProduct();
    }

    render() {
      const productItems = this.props.products.map( product =>(
          <div className="col-md-4 pt-4 pl-2" key={product.id}>
          <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
          <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
              <p>
                  {product.name}
              </p>
          </a>
          </div>
              <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      )
      )
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
            {productItems}
            </div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        products: state.data.products,
        loading: state.data.loading,
        error: state.data.error
    }
  };
  const mapActionsToProps = {
    fetchProduct: fetchProduct
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

My product container will show in a `div` all the products it fetched in the backend.

And now **My container filter:**

```
class FilterHome extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className="filterbt btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Filters</button>

                    <div className=" mt-4 d-flex flex-column">

                        <p className="textCategory">CATEGORY</p>
                        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Stat Trak</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Normal</p></a>
                        </div>

                        <p className="textCategory">EXTERIOR</p>
                        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p value={2} onChange={(e) => this.props.filterProducts(this.props.products, e.target.value)}>Factory New ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Minimal Wear ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Field Tested ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Well Worn ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Battle Scarred ()</p></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    products: state.data.products,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {filterProducts})(FilterHome);
```

and then I created an `action` and a redux to get the filtered product list and then send this filtered stripe to my div that displays the products.

**Action filter products:**

```
import {FILTER_PRODUCT} from '../constants/fetchTypes';

export const filterProducts = (products,value) => (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch({
        type:FILTER_PRODUCT,
        payload:{
            value:value,
            products:value === ''? products: products.filter(v => v.id_sub = value)
        }
    })
}
```

**My reducer filter:**

```
import {
    FETCH_SUCESS,
    FETCH_FAIL,
    FETCH_LOADING,
    FILTER_PRODUCT
  } from '../constants/fetchTypes';

  const initialState = {
    products: []
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case FILTER_PRODUCT:
        return {
          ...state,
          filteredProducts: action.payload.products
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  } return state;
    }
  }
```

I don't know how I can change the filtered products in my product div

Comment: Your `filterProducts` should probably be a simple helper function in the component if it doesn't change the underlying data. If the filtering is only affecting how the products are displayed by this component, but not changing any global state, you don't need to involve redux.

Comment: It will not change, but in my products container I need to display according to the filtered products.

Comment: Somehow I would need to pass these filtered products to my component products.

Comment: Could I do this without redux?

If you can help me I would be very grateful